# how to make a deep fragment to take the whole screen with a jetpack navigation and BottomNavigationView on screen?

Tags: android, android-fragments, navigation-drawer, bottomnavigationview, android-jetpack

I study the google example at https://github.com/android/architecture-components-samples/tree/master/NavigationAdvancedSample .And it works like this :

[image]

[image]

But I need the about fragment to take the whole screen.What is best practice?

I have try this :
`activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.root_activity,Detail())?.addToBackStack("About")?.commit()`

and get this:

[image]

the activity_main.xml:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:id="@+id/root_activity"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
tools:context="com.example.android.navigationadvancedsample.MainActivity">

<androidx.fragment.app.FragmentContainerView
    android:id="@+id/nav_host_container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="0dp"
    android:layout_weight="1" />

<com.google.android.material.bottomnavigation.BottomNavigationView
    android:id="@+id/bottom_nav"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    app:menu="@menu/bottom_nav"/>
```

I can set `activity?.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)?.visibility=View.GONE`
or `activity?.findViewById<BottomNavigationView>(R.id.bottom_nav)?.visibility=View.INVISIBLE`
But when it comes back,it looks like this,I think this is not good way:
[image]

**thanks!!**

Comment: You can set `visibility gone` of `BottomNavigationView' white replacing fragment.

Comment: I have tried this,but when it returns back from nested fragment ,the BottomNavigationView is invisible.

Answer (score 2):

You have to toggle visibility of BottomNavigationView as shown below:

```
NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener destinationChangedListener = new NavController.OnDestinationChangedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onDestinationChanged(@NonNull NavController controller, @NonNull NavDestination destination, @Nullable Bundle arguments) {
            if(destination.getId() == R.id.navigation_notifications){
                navView.setVisibility(View.GONE);
            }else{
                navView.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
            }

        }
    };
    navController.addOnDestinationChangedListener(destinationChangedListener);
```

Comment: didn't work. Add this code to MainActivity,but MainActivity has three navControllers to manage.

Comment: set visibility of bottomnavigationview in onDestinationChangedListener of NavController which handles BottomNavigationView

Comment: this works. But when all NavController have a few fragments that need to take the whole screen,this may take a lot code to handle

Answer (score -1):

in case anybody has ths same question,I post my answer here.

to work around ,I put BottomNavigationView into a MainFragment instead of MainActivity . And in the MainActivity dynamically instantiate the MainFragment,so I can replace the MainFragment as a whole in my deep child fragment .

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
    val container = FrameLayout(this)
    container.id = R.id.activity_container
    setContentView(container)
    supportFragmentManager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.activity_container,MainFragment()).commit()
}
```

}

in the nested fragment :
`activity?.supportFragmentManager?.beginTransaction()?.replace(R.id.activity_container,About())?.addToBackStack("Abouts")?.commit()`

final effect(have strip away the toolbar):
[image]

Comment: This approach relies on creating a new container on each rotation or any other configuration change or even after process death, therefore the Fragment auto-recreation will fail to recreate the active navigation history. I attempted to add `if(savedInstanceState == null) {` around the initializing fragment transaction as per FragmentManager contract, but due to the inherent flaw of creating a new container each time rather than relying on a concrete layout file, this approach would also most likely fail after process death. Therefore, Fragment state is lost, can't fix it, so I have to downvote